# how can I stop browser from auto start and redirecting?

Tags: android

my browser is redirecting automatically even when I haven't started the browser.Like, I am playing a soccer game suddenly a tab got opened and automatically start downloading uc browser or 9apps type applicationss.I tried to uninstall the browser but same thing start happening from other browser.

Comment: This site is for programming questions, I expect the game (or an ad within the game) is causing it to happen

Comment: not only game while watching videos or doing other works everytime.

Comment: UCBrowser is spam and is one of the most annoying browser. It's ads are mostly soft core and terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Which Browsers have you installed in your phone?

Do you have sync enabled in your browser in case of Firefox/Chrome. 
If Yes, do check for any nasty extensions in the list.

Also try to clear cache and data of all the Browsers you have on the phone.

Can you list the number of apps installed on the phone. Uninstall apps that you do not use.